# What did the angels fight about in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing Diablo 3, and it shows how Tyrael is like "yeah, I'm done, I'm going to go help the humans".

What were all the arch angels arguing about?

Comment: Could you cite where precisely in teh game this takes place? Tyraels background takes place throughout Diablo I, Diablo II, Diablo III and World of Warcraft.

Comment: It's all explained quite well within the game...

Comment: @ydobonebi, Tyreal is only referenced in World of Warcraft. The game does not further his story, and is not even the same universe as the Diablo series.

Comment: @Timelord64 Wasn't trying to imply that he did anything in WoW other than tag along :) My point was, I can't memorize the entire game lore and dialogue.

Comment: And for the record, Tyreal doesn't originally come of Diablo universe either.

Comment: That's fine, but to prevent confusing other users, @ydobonebi, Tyreals background is only explored in diablo 2 and diablo 3. The new game coming out, heroes of the storm, will also feature Tyreal, but may or may not develop his backstory

Comment: @ydobonebi you had my interest, now you have my attention...

Comment: @ydobonebi my attention as well, where does he originally come from then?

Answer (score 7):

If you paid attention to the clip, you will discover that Tyreal is arguing with the council about their refusal to get involved with the war between the Humans (descendants of the [Nephalem](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem)), and the realms of Hell. Due to their (the human's) lineage, the Angels deem unfit for their assistance/protection from the realms of Hell.

Tyreal; as the [Archangel of ***Justice***](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Tyrael) feels the High Council is being *unjust* in their refusal, hence his choice to remove himself from the High Council.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply put, Tyreal knew of the dangers that were about to take place, and the other angels did not care.**

Tyreal is known as the angel that sticks up for the humans. That said, the other angels are mostly shown to be unmoved by the events that befall sanctuary. When Tyreal finds out that the remaining Lesser Evils intend to invade Sanctuary, he means to help. But the other angels care very little for the humans, and in the end, heaven denied assistance.

You can read a more detailed analysis [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Tyrael#The_End_of_Days). Bear in mind that **Tyreal's background develops over both Diablo 2 and Diablo 3**, so if you have not played Diablo 2, a lot of it might be confusing and/or spoilers.